# Can't pass parameters to Servlet via jQuery POST

Tags: jquery, servlets, jsf-2, servlet-3.0

I'm sending a POST request using jQuery:

```
$.post(
'test',
{ foo: 'bar'}
);
```

And I have a simple servlet for processing it:

```
@WebServlet("/test")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
      Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = req.getParameterMap();
  }

}
```

But the requestMap in the servlet turns out to be empty. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**:
Forgot to mention that I call this script from the JSF Facelet page. Don't ask me why I bother manually issuing Ajax requests, and why I use servlets to process them. It's a long story. I know it's not a JSF'ish way.

After @BalusC answer, I tried adding a servlet filter like this:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns="/test")
public class TestFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void destroy() { }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }
}
```

And it worked! Not only I was able to get the parameters in the filter, but also they were accessible in the servlet! So, can somebody explain me what sort of magic is this?

Comment: What do you see with `firebug`?

Comment: I see that it's actually sending a POST request. At the same time I set the breakpoint in Eclipse, and I really catch this request, but without any parameters... I use Chrome Developer Tools, and it shows that the request is actually posted with all the required parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter map will be empty if some code in the request-response chain has invoked `request.getReader()` or `request.getInputStream()` beforehand. The HTTP request body can be read and parsed only once (the client ain't going to resend it multiple times on server's needs). Check all your filters.

Comment: I have no custom filters. I get a response from Facebook with access token, and I execute this script on page load to pass it to the Servlet. One note however: this script is invoked from JSF Facelet.

Comment: If `getReader()` or `getInputStream()` is called *before* `getParameter()`, `getParameterMap()`, etc, then the params will remain `null`. From the other way round, if you call `getParameter()`, etc, *before* the `getReader()` or `getInputStream()`, then they will return EOF. Debug your code to check if you aren't calling either of them (in)directly. That's all I can tell based on the symptoms.